# How to remove spacing in contempo blogger theme and make the sidebar visible in screen above 1024 px

Tags: css, themes, blogger, sidebar, blogspot

How to remove spacing in contempo blogger theme and make the sidebar visible in screen above 1024 px, the tutorials given on the net do not work properly.

Answer (score 1):

I think what exactly you are looking for is `"to show sidebar in screen which are smaller then 1440px but greater then 1024px"`.
If that is the case here is the post that might help you in making the suitable changes in CSS of your site to make it look the way you want it to look : [Link](http://www.tcbin.com/2017/12/sidebar-blogger-contempo-template-screen-sizes-smaller-than-1440px.html)

So basically Override the default css with our own :

```
  @media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  .sidebar-container {
    bottom: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
  }
  .sidebar-container {
    left: 0;
    right: auto;
  }
  .sidebar-container.sidebar-invisible {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.6,1);
            transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.6,1);
  }
  .sidebar-container.sidebar-invisible {
    -webkit-transform: translateX($(sidebar.width * -1));
        -ms-transform: translateX($(sidebar.width * -1));
            transform: translateX($(sidebar.width * -1));
  }
 .page_body{margin-left: 5%;margin-right: 5%;}

}
```

Followed by adjusting the margins:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1439px) {
    .page_body{margin-left: 250px;}
}
```

Comment: Can you summarize that link in case it goes dead?

Comment: Thanks, but I reverted back to the original template.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using ONLY css. Edit it from your template html editor page. Link your site and I could help you. Right click > Inspect element or press F12 in your browser and start playing around with the HTML and CSS styles on elements in your page.

Comment: Thanks, but I reverted back to the original template.